# Get autoscaling name from ecs ec2 instances

Tags: boto3, autoscaling, amazon-ecs

I have an ECS cluster, I want to stop those instance and it may be either autoscaling or not... so I started to create a script like this.

```
import boto3

CLUSTER='BBB'
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2') 
ecs = boto3.client('ecs')

ci_list_response = ecs.list_container_instances(
    cluster=CLUSTER )

ci_descriptions_response = ecs.describe_container_instances(
    cluster=CLUSTER,
    containerInstances=ci_list_response['containerInstanceArns'] )

for ci in ci_descriptions_response['containerInstances']:   
    print(ci['ec2InstanceId'])
```

I am able to get a list of ec2-instance ids, but struggling to get those instance's autoscale information. Please share your thoughts if any to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

ec2_client.describe_instances(instanceId)

In the response look for requesterId, that should give you the required information

https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html

Comment: Thanks, but received the following messages.. please check this link.. let me know........https://docs.google.com/document/d/13vWQcYBR7t9Bb6C1cTKbgE1_m6sTMA4jGrYtgEFRoP0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Looks like your request format is incorrect, the function expects a list of instance ids

Comment: What should i do to get those informations? could u plz guide me?